# Create Start date and end date off of date field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table

```
START_DT   END_DT    ID     NAME    ROLE       CUST_DT
6/22/18              1245   SMITH   CUST1    7/31/18 12:55:42
6/22/18              1245   SMITH   CUST1    7/31/18 13:56:50
6/22/18              1245   JACK    CUST2    7/31/18 13:56:50
5/1/18     5/30/18   5156   ROBERT  CUST1    5/01/18 12:25:25
5/1/18     5/30/18   5156   JOHN    CUST2    5/02/18 12:25:88
```

I would like the below output

```
 ID     NAME   ROLE   CUST_START_DT        CUST_END_DT  
1245   SMITH   CUST1   7/31/18 12:55:42    7/31/18 13:56:49   
1245   SMITH   CUST1   7/31/18 13:56:50           
1245   JACK    CUST2   7/31/18 13:56:50    
5156   ROBERT  CUST1   5/01/18 12:25:25    5/02/18 12:25:87     
5156   JOHN    CUST2   5/02/18 12:25:88
```

I'm not sure where to begin, perhaps I can you the lead/lag function?

Comment: You should give it a look to the analytic functions and the `OVER` clause.

Comment: How do you produce the new `CUST_END_DT` column?

Comment: Get in the habit of having the end_dt exactly match the following start_dt (not off by one second, or whatever), and "intervals" mean "including the start dt, but EXcluding the end dt". This, regardless of anything else. You will find that most in the profession use the same convention - besides it making everything a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query for expected output

```
create table start_end
(ID NUMBER,
NAME VARCHAR2(12),
ROLE VARCHAR2(10),
CUST_DT TIMESTAMP);


select id,name,role, CUST_DT CUST_START_DT, 
case when lead (CUST_DT) OVER ( partition by ID ORDER BY CUST_DT)=CUST_DT 
THEN NULL 
ELSE lead (CUST_DT) OVER ( partition by ID ORDER BY CUST_DT) - numToDSInterval( 1, 'second' )
END AS CUST_END_DT  
from start_end;
```